# XR2206 Signal generator amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, function-generator

Probably a silly question but I'm still a total noob on electronics. I got my hands on an old  non-functional XR2206 based function generator and I wanted to bring it back to life and in the meantime upgrade it with newer components.

From the old circuitry I could rescue the power supply, that delivers +5, +15 and -15V. I'm powering the XR2206 with 0 and + 15V and I got it to generate nice 1V amplitude waves (it works fine also in pulse mode).

The problem comes when I want to amplify the signals.

What I came up with is below:

[image: amplifier schematic]

(I'm using a LM358 but I have also the LM324, +5V is so far unused but I'm thinking to connect an Arduino to control the LCD/8 segment screen to show the frequency)

My idea is to get the signal from the 2206, couple it to AC and then use the +-15V to generate the output that goes to a second buffer op amp and then will go to a third op amp to regulate the final amplitude.

When I probe with the oscilloscope after C2 and with the op amp disconnected everything is fine (sine/triangle wave centered on 0V) but when I connect U1G2 the wave jumps up (depending on the values of R1 and R3) and the op amp outputs just +15V without any signal.

**UPDATE:**

Think twice, check trice. It turns out it was a faulty LM358. As a note to this, some commented that the LM358 is a horrible op amp. What would be a better choice?

Note 2: how do I reduce the crossover distortion? Resistor to GND?

Comment: So, this is really nothing against your *design*, just for future readers: don't use the LM358 if you can avoid it. It's an opamp that is so old, it's still available in round IC packages that predate DIL. Seriously, its spec are horrible by modern standards.

Comment: I thought so. I just happend to have some lying around and I thought to put them to use. What would be a better choice?

Comment: Please edit your circuit to show the power supply connections. Are you using +15 and ground, or +/- 15?

Comment: +/- 15V for the op amps and 0/+15V for the XR2206

Comment: have you tried adding a load (i.e. a resistor to GND) to the output of the first stage opamp?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure anymore because I tried a number of things but I thinks so and it didn't change anything. I will try again just to be sure

Comment: make it a rather "strong" resistor (ie rather small resistance in Ω) so that it doesn't "compete" with the TM2-R1-R3->GND loop

Comment: Well, the choice of amplifier of course depends on what you need to do – so, specify in and output specs, signal bandwidths, power to be offered and so on

Comment: I got the amplification stage completed but I ran into two problems. First is the op amp itself: after about 40 kHz the LM358 starts deforming the sine waves to triangle waves and then to almost only noise. Considering the following parameters, what is a good replacement? Range: 1Hz-1MHz, Voltage supply: +/-15V (max output 20 Vpp is acceptable), current and power are not a priority.
The second problem is a diode that I want to incorporate to have a half wave output. I'm using so far a 1N4148 but I noticed that it doesn't cut "cleanly" the waveform. Is there a better option? Schottky maybe?